# Is it possible to display XCode nib file on Windows?

Tags: windows, xcode, ios4

I'm currently working on migration of iPhone project to Android. And since my dev machine is Windows 7, I'm wondering if there's a tool that would allow me to view nib files on Windows?

Basically what I want is to view nib files at least as an image file (no properties, just to understand how a View should look like).

And I would also appreciate if someone could suggest a tool that understands an XCode project structure and lets browsing of Objective-C files easy on Windows.

So, I'm looking into an convinient way of migrating an iPhone app to Android on Windows platform.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Nib files basically consist of a bunch of serialized ObjC objects; without reimplementing a significant portion of Cocoa / AppKit, it'd be difficult to make much sense of them. You might be able to extract the view hierarchy and bounds with some work, but it's probably much easier overall to just copy the file over to a Mac and open it up.